# The Arabic text is reversed after converting Html to PDF through iText html2pdf

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm trying to convert an HTML page to a PDF file by using iText html2pdf, but I found the Arabic text is being reversed after the converting.
On the HTML page, the text starts with "#", but on the PDF, the text ends with "#", and the characters are totally wrong. check the following pictures for more details:
[HTML page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCCKB.png)
[PDF page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV80y.png)

Is there anyone who knows how to solve this?

**test.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
    <title>Arabic testing</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            direction: rtl;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>حاوية #</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@Test
public void convert() {
    File htmlFile = new File("/Users/scott/Downloads/pdf/test.html");
    File pdfFile = new File("/Users/scott/Downloads/pdf/test.pdf");

    try {
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(pdfFile.getPath());
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
        pdfDoc.setTagged();
        pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());

        ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
        converterProperties.setCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, false);
        fontProvider.addFont("/Users/scott/Downloads/pdf/Amiri-Regular.ttf");
        converterProperties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);

        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(htmlFile), pdfDoc, converterProperties);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Render PDF failed, ", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Youre setting your text direction to "right-to-left" using `direction: rtl;` in your CSS. Therefore the text on your webpage is reversed (which is correct for arabic). Your PDF doesnt seem to know about that to so it prints the text in the regular "left-to-right" text direction.

Comment: do you have the typography (pdfCalligraph) module loaded?

Comment: According to the suggestion from @andré-lemos, adding the typography module could solve this issue. Thanks @andré-lemos!

Answer (score 0):

according to the suggestion from @andré-lemos, adding the typography module could solve this issue. Thanks @andré-lemos!

Comment: Your answer might be seen as more useful if you could show the details of your solution.